# How to estimate curve length from random points along a (possibly not connected) curve

Tags: numerical-methods, plane-curves

I'm working with a closed, smooth, planar curve. I don't know the curve exactly, but I do have an effectively-random collection of points along the curve. What's a good way to estimate the curve length from that information?

I can think of two methods:

*EDIT: The curve I'm working with is the solution of f(x,y)=0, and I now see that -- in my case -- solutions to this are not necessarily connected. (I.e. it looks like the solutions are multiple, disjoint curves -- whether these are one curve or many is a matter of semantics.) That rules out method 1.*

<strike>1) Start at some point. Find the distance to the closest point. From that point, find the distance to the next closest point. Rinse, lather, repeat and sum up the distances.</strike>

2) If there are enough points, make a grid and mark all grid cells that have at least one point in them. The curve must pass through each of those cells, so the curve length can be estimated from the number of marked cells. (I guess, more specifically, this would be using the Cauchy-Crofton formula as described by Do Carmo on p 45-46 in his classic Differential Geometry book.) However, this method may run into trouble if there aren't points in every cell that the curve passes through.

The first method seems inefficient (have to repeatedly search through all the unused points) but accurate. The second would be faster, but less accurate.

Thoughts on those methods or other methods?

Comment: Why don't you sort the points first by increasing $x$ ? This will be done only onece. Is this suggestion totally stupid ?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your suggestion. I'm not trying to find the arclength of a curve y=f(x); I'm trying to find the arclength of a curve f(x,y)=0. How would ordering the points by x help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the first method. As you observed, it has unpleasant $O(n^2)$ behavior. If you care about efficiency, you need to do something to fix this. The standard way would be to use sorting, or some sort of spatial index, to reduce the number of comparisons you have to do. For example, set up a grid, as in your second algorithm. Make a pass through the list of points, finding out which cell each one falls in. For each cell, keep a list of the points it contains. Then, when looking for closest neighbors, you only have to look in the current point's cell and nearby ones. Some fine-tuning is required to decide how fine/coarse the grid should be.

Comment: I just realized that I'm working with curves that aren't necessarily connected. (They're usually connected, but I just found an example where they're not.) The second method could still work with them, but can the first method be modified to do so?

Comment: You'd need some heuristic method to distinguish between a figure-eight shape and two almost-touching circles. But both of these have roughly the same arclength, so I guess it doesn't matter (assuming arclength is the only thing you need). I'd say that the second method is still better unless the point set is very dense.